# Autopopulate Value Based on Master Inventory List in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have a master inventory list of ingredients/prices that have the following structure (simplified for this post) in a Google Sheet:

```
Ingredient     Price
Creatine       $10
Beta Alanine   $20
Citrulline     $15
Vitamin B12    $30
```

I have another Google Sheet (can make it another tab in the same sheet if that makes this exercise easier) where I'm doing manual quotes for customers. Right now this is a manual process where I manually type in the ingredients and go back and forth to the master to look up prices.

I know how to do a VLOOKUP to grab the price based on the value in the first cell.

```
 =VLOOKUP(D9,$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

I have that working.

What I would like to do is have a dropdown of ingredients, based on the master inventory list, and be able to start typing and it bring up ingredients that match the letters I have started to type. For example, type "C" and "Creatine" and "Citrulline" would pop up as options.

This would then use the VLOOKUP above to pull in the price.

How can I create this dropdown with autocomplete functionality?

Thank you for any help on this!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Data Validation`

Please have a look at the screenshots

[image]

**The above uses a range without a dropdown list in the cell.**

[image]

*You can also have it shown as in cell `B11`. Do notice the little triangle on the right of the cell.*

Comment: Thank you for this solution..exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Glad I could help and thank you for taking the time to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a data in `A1:B5`

First, create a data validation - `Data>>Data Validation` in cell `D1`

Then put the below formula in `D2`

```
=FILTER(A2:B,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,D1))
```

[image]

When you type in `D1` it'll be like type as you go